# getDay() return wrong day if day is with leading zero

Tags: javascript, date

I am facing this issue with javascript, I get yyyy-mm-dd dates from a database, but when I want to get the number of the week with getDay(), I get a wrong number if the day is with leading zero

[image: getDay() return wrong day if day is with leading zero]

---

I wrote a posible solution to parse MySql date into Javascript Date

```
function parseDate(str){
  var dt=str.replace(/[-T:]/g," ").split(" ");
  return new Date(dt[0],dt[1]-1,dt[2],dt[3]|0,dt[4]|0,dt[5]|0);
}

parseDate("2018-02-08");
//Thu Feb 08 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600

parseDate("2018-02-08 22:30:00");
//Thu Feb 08 2018 22:30:00 GMT-0600
```

Comment: Print the date object itself and the difference would become obvious.

Comment: Or do `new Date("2018-2-8").toISOString()`. See [MDN's documentation for the `dateString` overload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info on why.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan—no, don't do that. Parsing of non–standard strings is implementation dependent. "2018-2-8" it might be parsed as UTC, local or invalid.

Comment: You can simplify the parser a bit by splitting on non-digits: `str.split(/\D/)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG That was a rejoinder to zerkms' comment, to make it obvious how the `Date` object was parsing that string.